# How to execute Windows commands remotely from Linux machine using rdesktop command?

Tags: linux, windows

Is it possible to run Windows commands using `rdesktop` tool in Linux? I tried with `rdesktop -s` option:

```
rdesktop -u user -p 10.0.0.2 -s "cmd.exe"
```

but I'm not able to open the `cmd.exe` using the above command, also I tried with the full path:

```
rdesktop -u user -p'password' 10.0.0.2 -s "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
```

but there is no difference in the RDP session even if I use `-s`.

I'm trying to get a list of RDP sessions using `qwinsta /server` in Windows from Linux.

Comment: It's probably because only the default admin can do tasks without being promoted to prpceed. Any other account, even with the correct permissions, would be acting as admin.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/06/03/looking-forward-microsoft-support-for-secure-shell-ssh/

Comment: Have you looked at the psexec tools for windows? They might run under WINE.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a solution using `rdesktop` but I use a program called `winexe` on Linux to execute remote commands on Windows machines.  You can get the application from the following URL or use your distribution's software repository system to install it.

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/winexe/

UPDATE: SSL cert is self signed for the sourceforge link above, so I'm providing another link:

> https://github.com/skalkoto/winexe

Here's an example of the usage:

```
winexe -A credentials.cfg //remotehost "qwinsta /server"
```

You will want to create a credentials.cfg file with the login information as so:

```
username=user
password=pass
domain=workplace
```

Only supply the domain if it applies to you.  It's a best practice to not put your login credentials (especially password) on the command line.  Try running `cmd.exe` using the example above if you want an interactive prompt.  Nice thing about this approach is that you can use the output of the remote command in your Linux scripts or grep the output.

Comment: In winexe user should be "administrator" to work properly, but in my case, I'm trying with normal RDP user, so winexe won't work.

Comment: @Augustin: What does "should" mean? Did you read that somewhere, or have you tried it and it doesn't work if the username is any other than `administrator`? Have you actually tried it yet?

Comment: Winexe will install some packages in the Windows Machine, then only it will work and package installation is not possible with regular user.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the computer, install an ssh server on it.
On Linux you can use for example Overlook-Fing to find the IP of the computer.
Then you type
 `ssh username@ipaddress` into the Linux shell.

Example:

```
ssh Lenovo@192.168.0.100
```

Then type the user's password and you should have access to the computer's Windows Command Prompt.
You could also use telnet but ssh is encrypted.

Answer (score 4):

As of today, you could use `xfreerdp` with it's RemoteApp feature to execute specific software:

1. [Enable RemoteApps](http://techgenix.com/host-remoteapps-windows-pcs-part1/) on a Windows host. Should be as easy as [editing registry](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84393b01-295e-4c4f-9477-b8b45a8e297b/how-to-setup-remoteapp-mode-for-some-application-in-windows-10-professional?forum=win10itprosetup);
2. Install `xfreerdp` on your Linux host. There are [ready-to-use builds](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/PreBuilds) for Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, OpenSUSE and macOS.
3. Execute the command `xfreerdp /u:user /d:domain /p:password /app:"||calc" /v:server` where:

   - `/u:`- Windows user
   - `/d:`- Domain(could be `WORKGROUP` if not joined an AD)
   - `/p:`- Windows password
   - `/app:"||calc"` - App to be executed. Could be `cmd` as you want
   - `/v:`- IP address or Hostname of the Windows host.